# Generating Random string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, random

Can anyone tell me how can I generate a random string containing only letters in c#?
I basically want a Random value and fill it in my form. I want this value to contain letters only?
How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066707/how-do-i-generate-a-random-string-of-up-to-a-certain-length

Comment: or using LINQ
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `Random` class to generate random numbers between 1 and 26, and convert that to characters. Something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int length =  20;
var str = "";
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    str += ((char)(rnd.Next(1,26) + 64)).ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: There are already plenty of example of previous questions and answers + the OP didn't shown any attempt he tried.